# Surjectivity of family of morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be connected, smooth, real affine varieties and $\Phi\colon\mathbb{A}^1\times X\rightarrow Y$ a smooth morphism. Suppose that $\Phi(0,\cdot)$ is surjective.

Is it always true that $\Phi(t,\cdot)$ is surjective (or at least dominant) for $t$ outside a finite subset of $\mathbb{A}^1$?

I would definitely expect this to be true, but my algebraic geometry is quite rusty. I would also be happy with an answer in the algebraically closed case.